# how to set Pig Storage location to some another hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, location, apache-pig

I am running a PigScript through REST API and I want to store my Pig output to another hadoop cluster .Is there any way I set PigStorage to some other hdfs .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `distcp` to copy from one hdfs to another.

`distcp` is used to copy large amounts of data to and from hadoop file systems in parallel.

```
$ hadoop distcp hdfs://namenode1/foo hdfs://namenode2/bar
```